# laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new with Laravel and I have a problem which I don't understand.
I have а log form in my project and my method is **POST**. When I try a request the result is:

> 'The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try
>   again.'

But if I change the method to **GET**, It works fine.

Can someone tell me why is that and how to fix it? because of course I need  POST method.

Comment: PLease show your code!.

Comment: I found this helpful for improving the user experience: https://gist.github.com/jrmadsen67/bd0f9ad0ef1ed6bb594e#gistcomment-2677969

Answer (score 176, accepted):

This problem comes from the CSRF token verification which fails. So either you're not posting one or you're posting an incorrect one.

The reason it works for GET is that for a GET route in Laravel, there is no CSRF token posted.

You can either post a CSRF token in your form by calling:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or exclude your route (NOT RECOMMENDED DUE TO SECURITY) in `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`:

```
protected $except = [
    'your/route'
];
```

Comment: For anyone else viewing this, you can also put a meta tag in your site header which will be used with most requests.

Comment: @Erik I'm not really sure if the 2nd approach is fine. If we exclude a route in `VerifyCsrfToken.php` the route will be vulnerable to CSRF attack, I think

Comment: The second approach WOULD pose a security risk, this is true. However, there are use cases where you might not want to do CSRF verification. Such as AJAX calls.

Comment: @ErikBaars You still want to use CSRF if you're doing AJAX requests from an SPA to your backend. I do this with Laravel by getting the CSRF token on the initial request for the SPA and then maintaining an updated token by getting it from response headers using an HTTP interceptor.

Comment: In my case the Laravel Auth login system was giving the "expire page error". I had to check my /resources/views/auth/login.blade.php to have this line: {{ csrf_field() }} . thats it!

Comment: @ErikBaars After excluding the route it is throwing a 404 error.

Comment: I have added route in exception because post request is coming from payment gateway.

Answer (score 35):

In my case, I've got the same error message and then figured out that I've missed to add `csrf_token` for the form field. Then add the `csrf_token`.

Using form helper that will be,

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or without form helper that will be,

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If that doesn't work, then-

**Refresh the browser cache**

and now it might work, thanks.

**Update For Laravel 5.6**

Laravel integrates new `@csrf` instead of `{{ csrf_field() }}`. That looks more nice now.

```
<form action="">
   @csrf
   ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request. You may use the `csrf_field` helper to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ...
</form>
```

It doesn't work, then Refresh the browser cache and now it might work,

For more details open link  :- [CSRF Protection in Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf)

**UPDATE:**

With Laravel 5.6 using Blades templates, it's pretty easy.

```
<form method="POST" action="/profile">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

For more details open link :- [CSRF Protection in Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf)

Comment: This is not the perfect solution. Because in case of User, how they will know that they have to delete the cache.

Comment: When we update our application, a browser may still use old files. If you don’t clear your cache, Old files can access problems when you apply. for more details read this  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Answer (score 6):

Verify that your config/session.php file contains this line

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

Then remove the `SESSION_DOMAIN` line in your .env file

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on this a bit? Why, what does it do ?

Comment: Doesn't that in essence amounts to this code:
`'domain' => null,`
?

Comment: Furthermore, my first conclusion that this solved my problem turned out to be false. It was actually my browser cache that was the issue. I first opened this page in an incognito window of the browser and then it worked.

Answer (score 4):

In my case , I added ob_start(); at the top of my **index.php** on server and everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Bro you saved me...the only solution that worked for me

Answer (score 4):

**Excluding URIs From CSRF Protection:**

Sometimes you may wish to exclude a set of URIs from CSRF protection. For example, if you are using Stripe to process payments and are utilizing their webhook system, you will need to exclude your Stripe webhook handler route from CSRF protection since Stripe will not know what CSRF token to send to your routes.

Typically, you should place these kinds of routes outside of the web middleware group that the  RouteServiceProvider applies to all routes in the routes/web.php file. However, you may also exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the $except property of the VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i had same problem. use 'clear browsing data' in chrome. maybe solve your problem.

Comment: This is not the perfect solution. Because in case of User, how they will know that they have to delete the cache.

Comment: Exactly it is not best solution.

Comment: it worked for me after a lot of search finally this answer solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are using the default CSRV middleware from Laravel's installation. To solve, remove this line from your Kernel.php:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

This is fine if you are build an API. However, if you are building a website this is a security verification, so be aware of its risks.

Answer (score 3):

Tried different solutions to solve the problem for several weeks without success.

The problem I was facing was caused by upgrading from laravel 5.0 to 5.5 and forgot to update config/session.php

If anyone is facing the problem, try to update the config/session.php to match the version on Laravel you are running

Comment: I was searching for hours, this was also my exact problem, but I upgraded to 5.7. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I have tried many solutions. but none worked for me. then I found out that for some reason I was using this in my .env file:

SESSION_DOMAIN= myapp.me

and as soon as I put it back to null, everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 2):

if your config is set: `SESSION_DRIVER=file` you have to check if your session directory is writable. Check `storage/framework/session`

Comment: Also check if your *disk is full*. Took me hours to realize that it can't write the session file to disk...

Answer (score 2):

Place `{{csrf_field()}}` Into your `form` tag

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have already included the **CSRF token** in your form. Then you are getting the error page possibly because of cache data in your form.

Open your terminal/command prompt and run these commands in your project root.

1. `php artisan cache:clear`
2. `php artisan config:clear`
3. `php artisan route:clear`
4. `php artisan view:clear`,

Also try to **clear the browser cache** along with running these commands.

Answer (score 2):

First, include csrf in your form.

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

if the problem didn't solve, then use `ob_start();` at the very start of index.php.

```
<?php ob_start();
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was '**space**' before `<?php` in one of my config file.
This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just place this code inside the form

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token() ?>" />
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action=" ">                                                                         <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token() ?>" />                                                                                                                            /* create your form*/                                                                                    </form>

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error so i just removed this line from my .env file

SESSION_DRIVER=yourwebsite.com

Answer (score 1):

Still anyone have this problem, use following code inside your form as below.

```
 echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "'. csrf_token().'" >';
```

Comment: What does "inside your form" mean? Why do you want to echo something directly and not use a Twig template?

Comment: "Inside your form" means inside your <form></form> tags. you can use above code without echoing.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `@csrf` inside your form tag.

Or you can include `csrf_token` in the header to send it with every request.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to change **form action** with Javascript you will have the same problem

1.*first* you need to use  instead of `{!!Form::open() !!} {!! close() !!}` in laravel

2.*second* you most begin your action with `https://www.example.com +your Route`

**Do not Forget www in your url!!!**

Answer (score 0):

In my case the same problem was caused because I forgot to add `>` at the end of my hidden input field, like so: `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}"`

So, I fixed it by adding it:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Funny  but it works for me. i realised this is Caused because of default HTML TAG in laravel code. 
Use    /* */   or  {{-- --}}  instead

Or Try to Remove Recently Html Coment in you code...
Or change Html Comment to Php Comment...
Or try to run Any Worng artisan command like  php artisan clean browser And See if it output any HTML Commented data along with it error...

Answer (score 0):

**We got it working** by copying the routes from Router.php instead of using Auth::routes(), these are the routes you need:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been satisfactorily answered, but I wanted to mention a fix that worked in my case. I added `{{ csrf_field() }}` and it still didn't work.

Then I remembered that I blocked all cookies for development purposes, which can be nice when you change the page and want to refresh it.

Once I changed the settings to stop blocking all cookies in `MS Edge browser` the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by just adding `@csrf` in form tag

`Laravel 5.6` doesn't support `{{ csrf_field() }}` just add `@csrf` in place of `{{ csrf_field() }}`

**larvel_fix_error.png**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. It may be **csrf token** do not have in your form. You have to use `@crsf` or `{{ csrf_field() }}`
2. If you are use csrf on your form. It may be cache. Clear your app cache.

   ```
   php artisan cache:clear
   php artisan view:clear
   php artisan cache:clear
   ```

   And clear your browser cache.
3. If errors again show you, then create a new key

   ```
   php artisan key:generate
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still looking for an answer to this issue. For me it happens when I'm switching between local and production server and I'm logged on both sites. To fix the issue, just clear the session.

just set the `'expire_on_close' => true` in `config\session.php` and restart your browser

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through this problem, tried all the solutions proposed here (and the internet) without success for 5 days.

In my case my environment:

**Laravel**: 5.5

**PHP**: 7.2

**SSL**: production

**Apache**

**CENTOS**

The problem is that I had automated the deployment using the git --bare repository with ansimble.

And all folders when pushing were with permission **0775** (inherited from the git user). When ansinble was run it replicated this permission to all folders. When composing install for example, all vendor folders also had this permission.

The **csrf**, has a policy of blocking what is considered insecure, especially if you use an encrypted environment (SSL).

I only realized the problem when I decided to carry out the deployment manually, zipped the project, uploaded it, unzipped it and ran the commands to generate the caches and dependencies. And then I realized that this way all folders were with permission **0755** (inherited from the system user). And this is the default permission that is considered safe.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems to be an issue in my web browser (Firefox for Android) or my smartphone with full storage. In another browsers and devices it works. By the way, the issue happens only when I send files through the form, I realized I currently can't upload files from my smartphone through this browser in any websites like https://filebin.net.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple for me. maybe the sessions folder is missing in storage/framework/sessions

Answer (score 0):

Some time its issue with the server storage. In my case server storage was full so it could not write any session to file.So freeing out some server storage solved the issue. Also sometimes it the issue of csrf if we forget to include csrf in post field.

Answer (score -3):

Go into 
`App/Kernel.php` and comment
`\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`.

Comment: This would disable CSRF validation all together, which is not recommended.