# Laravel 5.5 always shows "The page has expired due to inactivity"

Tags: laravel-5, authentication

I have upgraded from laravel 5.4 to 5.5. Whenever I try to login, it says "The page has expired due to inactivity Please refresh and try again".

I am using {{csrf_field()}} and also tried to clear browsing data but this is still existing.

Can anybody help me to get rid of this issue ?

Comment: Same question with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149561/laravel-5-5-the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-please-refresh-and-try-again/47496472#47496472 And my Answer was this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47496472/5385845

Comment: The issue is not the same as @samtax01 claims. I'm also experiencing the same problem, only solution appears to be disabling the csrf check on some routes.