# The page has expired due to in activity. PHP Curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I want to scrape some data in the website but before that I must login first. I used PHP Curl to remotely access Laravel website. I don't know if the execution of logging in was successful because it direct me to page that says "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.". Sorry for I am really new in PHP curl :(.

Note: I am using NATIVE PHP, I found some ways but only applicable for laravel. :(

This is my code:

```
**This is my client.php**
public function login()
{
    // TODO: Implement login() method.
    $this->curl->setPost(array("email" => Client::USER_HTTP, 
    "password" => 
    Client::PASS_HTTP));
    $this->curl->setHTTP(Client::USER_HTTP, Client::PASS_HTTP);
    $response = $this->curl->execute("http://nabepero.xyz/login/");
    $this->curl->closeSession();

    return $response;
}

**This is my index.php**
include 'vendors/simple_html_dom.php';
include 'vendors/Curl.php';
include 'src/Client.php';

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->login();
echo $response;

**This is my curl.php**
<?php
/*
* Curl Class
*/
class Curl {
    /**
     * @var $ch
     */
    private $ch;

    /**
     * @const
     */
    const COOKIE_PATH = '/cookie.txt';

    /**
     * The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP 
       request.
     * @var string
     */
    private $userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en- 
    US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6';

    /**
     * Curl constructor.
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        if($this->ch == null)
        {
            $this->ch = curl_init();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param array $params
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPost($params = array())
    {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $username
     * @param string $password
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setHTTP($username = '', $password = '')
    {
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, 
    constant('CURLAUTH_ANY'));
        curl_setopt($this->ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . 
    $password);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the request & return the results
     * @param $url
     * @return mixed
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute($url)
    {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

        $cookieFile = dirname(__FILE__).self::COOKIE_PATH;
        curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
        curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile);
        curl_setopt ($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);

        $response = curl_exec ($this->ch);
        if ($response === FALSE)
        {
            curl_close($this->ch);
            throw new \Exception("Opps, An error has occurred while 
    trying scrape data!",500);
        }
        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * close a session
     */
    public function closeSession()
    {
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149561/laravel-5-5-the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-please-refresh-and-try-again)

Comment: I am using native php and trying to access a laravel website. @PrabhjotSinghKainth

Comment: This is an issue of Laravel, kindly check the website on which you are hitting (the laravel website). You have to make changes in laravel website as suggested in the above link.

Comment: You must have to have access to that Laravel website , without that I can`t help.

Comment: change your code 

    `$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);`

Comment: @Hamelraj it seems that the my login was successful but it automatically logout my session or idk.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I need your help dude :(

Comment: hey you need to pass csfr i guess

Comment: @Hamelraj okay let me try

Comment: @Hamelraj still the same dude :(

Comment: just try some GET method API and check you getting response .... for testing

Comment: I used postman and still it returns "The page has expired due to inactivity". @Hamelraj

Comment: Can I communicate with you via facebook or something? @Hamelraj

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth can I communicate with you in facebook?

Comment: yes https://www.facebook.com/pravin.rajn