# Page Expired Due to Inactivity error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I m trying to run my application. After login it redirects to home page where i m getting **Page Expired Due to Inactivity Pls refresh and try again**
How to resolve this. I also tried passing CSRF token but still i m getting same error.
Please help to fix this

Comment: please do research it is already solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149561/laravel-5-5-the-page-has-expired-due-to-inactivity-please-refresh-and-try-again

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes only from the CSRF token .
May be u have send csrf token in wrong way.
Use like this

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If u still face problem try to check by making that url form POST to GET type